# Custom glBlendFunc a lot slower than native

Tags: c++, opengl, shader, glblendfunc

I'm trying to do my own custom glBlendFunc through fragment shaders, however, my solution is a lot slower than the native glBlendFunc, even when they do the exact blending function.

I was wondering if anyone had any suggestion on how to do this in a more efficient way.

My solution works something like this:

```
void draw(fbo fbos[2], render_item item)
{
   // fbos[0] is the render target
   // fbos[1] is the previous render target used to read "background" to blend against in shader
   // Both fbos have exactly the same content, however they need to be different since we can't both read and write to the same texture. The texture we render to needs to have the entire content since we might not draw geometry everywhere.

   fbos[0]->attach(); // Attach fbo
   fbos[1]->bind(1); // Bind as texture 1

   render(item);

   glCopyTexSubImage2D(...); // copy from fbos[0] to fbos[1], fbos[1] == fbos[0]
}
```

fragment.glsl

```
vec4 blend_color(vec4 fore) 
{   
    vec4 back = texture2D(background, gl_TexCoord[1].st); // background is read from texture "1"
    return vec4(mix(back.rgb, fore.rgb, fore.a), back.a + fore.a);  
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet for improving the performance of FBO-based blending is [NV_texture_barrier](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/NV/texture_barrier.txt). Despite the name, AMD has implemented it as well, so if you stick to Radeon HD-class cards, it should be available to you.

Basically, it allows you to ping-pong without heavyweight operations like FBO binding or texture attachment operations. The specification has a section towards the bottom that shows the general algorithm.

Another alternative is [EXT_shader_image_load_store](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/shader_image_load_store.txt). This will require DX11/GL 4.x class hardware. OpenGL 4.2 recently promoted this to core with [ARB_shader_image_load_store](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/shader_image_load_store.txt).

Even with this, as Darcy said, you're never going to beat regular blending. It uses special hardware structures that shaders can't access (since they happen after the shaders have run). You should only do programmatic blending if there is some effect that you absolutely cannot accomplish any other way.

Comment: NV_texture_barrier enables me to render to and read from the same texture simultaneously, correct?

Comment: @ronag: Sort of. It's best that you read the extension spec, but the general gist of it is that you can read and write to the same texture as long as you're not doing so from the _same place_. And that you use the barrier appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

It is a lot more efficient because blending operations are built directly into the GPU hardware, so you probably aren't going to be able to beat it for speed. Having said that,make sure you have depth-testing, back-face culling , hardware blending, and any other unneeded operations turned off. I can't say it will make a huge difference, but it may make some.